# selectInput choices dependent on another selectInput for R Shiny Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have an interesting problem with a shiny app I'm trying to build using Flexdashboard. Essentially I have a sidebar with two selectInput drop downs. I would like the choices in the second selectInput to be dependent upon the choice in the first. My approach thus far has been to switch between two dynamically generated options for the second input. This [Dynamic UI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html) shiny example is essentially exactly what I'm trying to do, but I think I'm having trouble translating from the server/ui format to a Rmarkdown format.

At this point I have the following simplified code that produces the first selectInput, but instead of a second selectInput it's just drawing a block of html code.

````
---
title: "Shiny Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

Tab1
===============================================================================  

Inputs {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput('type', label = 'Input 1',
            choices = c('choice1', 'choice2'))

reactive({
  switch(input$type,
         'choice1' = selectInput('select2', 
                                 label = 'Input 2',
                                 choices = c('choice3', 'choice4')),
         'choice2' = selectInput('select3', label = 'Input 3',
                                 choices = c('choice5', 'choice6')))
  })
```

Column {data-width=600}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Test Output

```{r}

```
````

[Test picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2yIt.png)

I have a feeling that I'm missing something very simple, but I can't seem to find anything that deals with this problem in the context of Flexdashboard. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way to do it is to process it (`input$type`) on the server side in a `renderUI` and then `uiOutput` in `ui`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput('type', label = 'Input 1',
              choices = c('choice1', 'choice2')),
  uiOutput("mychoices")
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$mychoices <- renderUI({
    switch(input$type,
           'choice1' = selectInput('select2', 
                                   label = 'Input 2',
                                   choices = c('choice3', 'choice4')),
           'choice2' = selectInput('select3', label = 'Input 3',
                                   choices = c('choice5', 'choice6')))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked great (with a few tweaks to fit with flexdashboard)

Comment: @Plato_of_the_Wilds would you be able to show how you adapted the above solution to flex dashboard as you say you did in the comment above? (then you can accept your own answer) I am running into the exact same question as you a year later but don't know how to adapt it to shiny flex dashboard.